# Можно ли задать значения wow.js сразу для всех элементов?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет. Мне нужно прописать значение wow так, чтобы на всех страницах срабатывало появление. Попробовав через css ничего не сработало. Попробовал вписать html код в header и footer, тоже не сработало. А прописывать на каждой странице  для каждого элемента - это слишком долго. Возможно кто-то меня понял, и сможет мне помочь. Спасибо

Comment: так давайте по порядку - что надо сделать ?

Comment: Если я Вас правильно понял, то берёте jQuery, получаете все элементы, которым надо задать появление, и присваиваете соответствующий класс: $('.elements').addClass('wow fadeInLeft'). Только этот скрипт должен отработать раньше, чем отработает wow.js, иначе ничего не произойдёт.